# Can I determine the statistical significance of conditional probabilities?

Tags: statistical-significance, conditional-probability, experiment-design, conditional-expectation

I have the following table of conditional probabilities.

```
       | pre work | positive outcome based on pre work type 
 group | done     | multi choice       | symbolic           
-------|----------|--------------------|--------------------
 A     | YES      | 0.51               | 0.33               
 B     | YES      | 0.42               | 0.56
```

Looking at the table above, is there any statistical test that I can use to confirm/reject that subjects in groups A who have done pre work did better preparing with symbolic vs multi choice work?

(it looks like the hypothesis is rejected, but the question holds anyway)

Comment: I really wanted to help but this question seems too long. I think you'll get more attention if you make it as short as possible and erase everything unnecessary.

Comment: @YairDaon Try now?

Comment: I think that if both groups did prework you cannot draw any conclusion on the effect of prework. Unless you make a prior assumption on those who did not do prework. Also, thanks for making this shorter but it might be too short now. I know I'm being annoying but I'm only trying to help (both by answering your question and by helping you attract more  attention).

Comment: Can you clarify which measurements you want to compare? Is it (`prework & A & symbolic`) versus (`prework & A & multi choice`)? Or do you want to quantify some sort of effect where the group B treatment simultaneously improves `symbolic` outcomes and worsens `multi choice`?

Comment: @YairDaon you are right that all did some pre work, but we chose two different types of pre work to reduce the impact of a lack of a true control group. @eric_kernfeld the second. The hypothesis is that `symbolic` helps more than `multi choice`. In practice, I don't think we see that effect taking place, so I'm also interested in how I can reject that hypothesis. It seems that the only effect shows between the slice that did and did not do pre work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also know the size of each group to estimate the error of the estimates of your conditional probabilities. If in the A-YES-symbolic group only 1 of 3 people succeeded, the estimate 0.33 of the success rate is less reliable than if it's 1000 of 3000. If you don't have that information, I don't think any statistical test would apply.

**Update**: ok, you have the information, perfect. The rest is just Z-test for independent proportions. Fill the following table with your data:

```
       |               |  # of outcomes 
 group | pre work type | positive | total           
-------|---------------|----------|-------
 A     | multi choice  | k_1      | n_1               
       | symbolic      | k_2      | n_2
```

Let $p_1$ be the probability of positive outcome in multi choice group, $p_2$ — in symbolic group. To test $H_0\colon p_1=p_2$, calculate $$Z = \frac{\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2}{\sqrt{P\left(1-P\right)\left(\frac1{n_1} + \frac1{n_2}\right)}}, $$
$$\hat{p}_1 = \frac{k_1}{n_1}, \;\hat{p}_2=\frac{k_2}{n_2}, \; P = \frac{\hat{p}_1n_1+\hat{p}_2n_2}{n_1+n_2}.$$
Under $H_0$ $Z$ would be distributed as $N\left(0,1\right)$, so, if you have $H_1\colon p_1\neq p_2$, then your p-value is $p=2\left(1-\Phi\left(\left|Z\right|\right)\right)$, where $\Phi$ is a standard normal cumulative distribution function.

It might be a good idea to calculate confidence interval for the difference between probabilities as well, so you would have an estimate of the effect size with explicitly specified uncertainty.

Comment: In fact I have that information, and that's how I computed the conditional probabilities – they are basically derived with Bayes' formula, as we can assume the events are independent.

Comment: @Morpheu5 As far as I know, usage and Bayes' rule and testing hypotheses don't mix... In a Bayesian setting, all information is encapsulated in the posterior and hypothesis testing is redundant. Anyone cares to refute this statement? I'm interested.

Comment: Evgeniy - great answer, would upvote again if I could. One thing though - the distribution is only approximately normal, is it not? If OP doesn't have too much data this holds in a modified form? Thanks.

Comment: @YairDaon yes, this is CLT-based asymptotical solution. For one-sample problem there is an exact test based on binomial distribution, but I don't think the same exists for two independent samples.